# Combobox value member to be inserted into another table

Tags: c#, mysql

Using Visual Studio and MySQL. I have a table Genre which contains two Columns - ID and Genre.

I've created a Combo box in Visual Studio with

1. Data Source: Genre table
2. Display Member- Genre (column)
3. Value ember - ID (column)

I want to take the ID(presumably Value Member) of the Displayed Member and insert it into another table. When I use the following code to insert the Value Member into a textBox just to see if the value is correct

```
textBox3.Text = comboBox1.ValueMember.ToString();
```

It shows 'ID' as a string.

I've tried a workaround with using the selected value as ID as well and the following code:

```
 textBox2.Text = comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();

           int anInteger;
           anInteger = Convert.ToInt16(textBox2.Text);
           anInteger = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
           int i = anInteger + 1;
```

The code I use to add the ID into the other table is

```
 SqlCommand xp4 = new SqlCommand("Insert into BookGenre(Genre_Id, Books_Id) Values (@textBox1, @newId2)", test);
           xp4.Parameters.Add("@textBox1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = i;
           xp4.Parameters.Add("@newId2", SqlDbType.Int).Value = newId2;
           test.Open();
           xp4.ExecuteNonQuery();
           test.Close();
```

however when I try to execute the program I get an error:

> Additional information: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_BookGenre_Genre". The conflict occurred in database "BookStoreBiggest", table "dbo.Genre", column 'ID'.

Comment: Your real problem is understanding your table relationships. Not the combobox

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting BookGenre, you must first insert them into table Genre. (The relationship between the two must match values) That is what the FOREIGN KEY constraint is requiring.

Comment: The Genre table have rows in it. I want to use these rows without adding anything to the table. Is it possible to take the ID of the selected Genre and add it to BookGenre?

Comment: The Foreign Key is referencing another column in the table Genre. Go into SQL and remove that foreign key in the table BookGenre and then you should be able to add to that table without the values matching in the other table "Genre"

Comment: Is there a workaround as I need the The Foreign Key to BookGenre as I'll use this later for creating views?

Comment: Just go into SQL and insert the values into the table 'Genre' first. Then insert them into the BookGenre table through your code. these 'rules' in SQL cannot be worked around, they are pretty straight forward.